# Unable to build Unity Container - Prism

Tags: c#, wpf, inversion-of-control, unity-container, prism

I am trying to use prism in my WPF application. So far i have configured my container and View model locator like this:

```
   protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {



        Container.RegisterType<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        Container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        Container.RegisterType<IDbFactory, DbFactory>();
        Container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>("UnitOfWork", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        Container.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>("UnitOfWork");
        Container.RegisterType<IDbFactory, DbFactory>("DbFactory", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        Container.Resolve<IDbFactory>("DbFactory");
        Container.RegisterType<IRegionManager, RegionManager>();
        Container.RegisterInstance<IRegionManager>(new RegionManager(), new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());


        #region Register Repositories

        Container.RegisterType<IVendorRepository, VendorRepository>();

        Container.RegisterType<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
        Container.RegisterType<IReceiveablesRepository, ReceiveablesRepository>();
        Container.RegisterType<IProductUnitsRepository, ProductUnitRepository>();
        Container.RegisterType<IPaymentRepository, PaymentRepository>();
        Container.RegisterType<IItemRepository, ItemRepository>();
        Container.RegisterType<IInvoiceMasterRepository, InvoiceMasterRepository>();
        Container.RegisterType<IInvoiceDetailRepository, InvoiceDetailRepository>();
        Container.RegisterType<IExpenseTypeRepository, ExpenseTypeRepository>();
        Container.RegisterType<IExpenseRepository, ExpenseRepository>();
        Container.RegisterType<ICustomerRepository, CustomerRepository>();
        Container.RegisterType<ICategoryRepository, CategoryRepository>();
        Container.RegisterType<IAddressesRepository, AddressesRepository>();
        #endregion
        #region Register Services

        Container.RegisterType<IVendorService, VendorService>();
        Container.RegisterType<IUserService, UserService>();
        Container.RegisterType<IReceiveablesService, ReceiveablesService>();
        Container.RegisterType<IProductUnitService, ProductUnitService>();
        Container.RegisterType<IPaymentService, PaymentService>();

        Container.RegisterType<IItemService, ItemService>();
        Container.RegisterType<InvoiceMasterService, InvoiceMasterService>();
        Container.RegisterType<IInvoiceDetailService, InvoiceDetailService>();
        Container.RegisterType<IExpenseTypeService, ExpenseTypeService>();
        Container.RegisterType<IExpenseService, ExpenseService>();
        Container.RegisterType<ICustomerService, CustomerService>();
        Container.RegisterType<ICategoryService, CategoryService>();
        Container.RegisterType<IAddressesService, AddressesService>();

        #endregion

        Container.RegisterType<IDbFactory, DbFactory>("DbFactory", new InjectionConstructor());
        Container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        Container.RegisterType<IDbFactory, DbFactory>();
        //Container.RegisterType<IService, >();
        Container.RegisterType<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>(new PerThreadLifetimeManager());

        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<Billing>();
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<Sales>();
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<Management>();
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<Home>();
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<Orders>();
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<Purchases>();



    }
   protected override void ConfigureViewModelLocator()
    {
        base.ConfigureViewModelLocator();
        Container.RegisterInstance(new DbFactory());
        Container.RegisterInstance(new UnitOfWork(Container.Resolve<DbFactory>()));
        Container.RegisterType<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        Container.RegisterType<IRegionManager, RegionManager>();
        Container.RegisterInstance(new UserRepository(Container.Resolve<DbFactory>()),new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        Container.RegisterInstance(new UserService(Container.Resolve<UnitOfWork>(),Container.Resolve<UserRepository>()));
        Container.RegisterInstance(new VendorRepository(Container.Resolve<DbFactory>()),new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        Container.RegisterInstance(new VendorService(Container.Resolve<UnitOfWork>(),Container.Resolve<VendorRepository>()));
        Container.RegisterInstance(new ReceiveablesRepository(Container.Resolve<DbFactory>()),new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        Container.RegisterInstance(new ReceiveablesService(Container.Resolve<UnitOfWork>(),Container.Resolve<ReceiveablesRepository>()));
        Container.RegisterInstance(new ProductUnitRepository(Container.Resolve<DbFactory>()),new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        Container.RegisterInstance(new ProductUnitService(Container.Resolve<UnitOfWork>(), Container.Resolve<ProductUnitRepository>()));
        Container.RegisterInstance(new PaymentRepository(Container.Resolve<DbFactory>()),new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        Container.RegisterInstance(new PaymentService(Container.Resolve<UnitOfWork>(), Container.Resolve<PaymentRepository>()));
        Container.RegisterInstance(new ItemRepository(Container.Resolve<DbFactory>()),new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        Container.RegisterInstance(new ItemService(Container.Resolve<UnitOfWork>(), Container.Resolve<ItemRepository>()));
        Container.RegisterInstance(new InvoiceMasterRepository(Container.Resolve<DbFactory>()),new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        Container.RegisterInstance(new InvoiceMasterService(Container.Resolve<UnitOfWork>(), Container.Resolve<InvoiceMasterRepository>()));
        Container.RegisterInstance(new InvoiceDetailRepository(Container.Resolve<DbFactory>()),new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        Container.RegisterInstance(new InvoiceDetailService(Container.Resolve<UnitOfWork>(), Container.Resolve<InvoiceDetailRepository>()));
        Container.RegisterInstance(new ExpenseRepository(Container.Resolve<DbFactory>()),new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        Container.RegisterInstance(new ExpenseService(Container.Resolve<UnitOfWork>(), Container.Resolve<ExpenseRepository>()));
        Container.RegisterInstance(new ExpenseTypeRepository(Container.Resolve<DbFactory>()),new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        Container.RegisterInstance(new ExpenseTypeService(Container.Resolve<UnitOfWork>(), Container.Resolve<ExpenseTypeRepository>()));
        Container.RegisterInstance(new CustomerRepository(Container.Resolve<DbFactory>()),new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        Container.RegisterInstance(new CustomerService(Container.Resolve<UnitOfWork>(), Container.Resolve<CustomerRepository>()));
        Container.RegisterInstance(new CategoryRepository(Container.Resolve<DbFactory>()),new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        Container.RegisterInstance(new CategoryService(Container.Resolve<UnitOfWork>(), Container.Resolve<CategoryRepository>()));
        Container.RegisterInstance(new AddressesRepository(Container.Resolve<DbFactory>()),new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        Container.RegisterInstance(new AddressesService(Container.Resolve<UnitOfWork>(), Container.Resolve<AddressesRepository>()));
        Container.RegisterType<IRegionManager, RegionManager>();
        Container.RegisterInstance<IRegionManager>(new RegionManager(), new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());



        ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewModelFactory((o, type) => Container.Resolve(type));
    }
```

after this when i try to run my application it breaks down on bootstrap.run() and following exception is throw:

> Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.IServiceLocator", name = "(none)".
>   Exception occurred while: while resolving.
>
> ### Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.IServiceLocator, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
>
> At the time of the exception, the container was:
>
> Resolving Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.IServiceLocator,(none)

Comment: Can you please provide what version you're using for Prism, Unity and ServiceLocator

Comment: Common Service locator 2.0.1 , Unit 5.3.2, Prism.wpf 6.3.0, Prism Unit 6.3.0, Prism.Core 6.3.0,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you're getting errors is that you are using incompatible versions. Prism 6.3 is built against Unity 4.0.1 and CommonServiceLocator 1.3.0. The newer versions of of CommonServiceLocator and Unity contain several breaking changes that make it incompatible with Prism 6.3, including a change of namespaces.

Please update to the Prism 7 preview for compatibility with Unity 5 and CommonServiceLocator 2. You can get a full list of changes within Prism 7 itself [here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/releases/tag/7.0.0-pre5). I will say that there are a number of breaking changes that we've added particularly in the latest preview for WPF.

Comment: prism 7 is only available for xamarin.forms while i am using for WPF

Comment: @NaveedKhan Prism 7 is available for WPF, and is also what I referenced in my answer to you. Please read the notes in the link I included in the answer above you will see that Xamarin Forms, WPF and UWP all have previews for Prism 7. You will also see it if you go to NuGet.

Comment: Now after configuring application with latest prism and using PrismApplication i am facing this error: {"Cannot create more than one System.Windows.Application instance in the same AppDomain."}

Comment: Make sure you aren't using the bootstrapper anymore

Comment: Then how should i initialize application

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail for your question. From my admittedly simplistic testing (file->new project) of the new API I only actually needed to migrate Create Shell from the Bootstrapper to my App class. Obviously real apps will need a little more setup like for Modules... But this was my full code: 

    public partial class App : PrismApplication
    {
        protected override Window CreateShell()
        {
            return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
        }
    }